# Beamer notes and framebreaks

Tags: beamer, allowframebreaks

I have slides with manual `\framebreak`s. How can I do something similar inside `note` command?

I would like to have my notes displayed not only on the last slide of the group but spread across the group.

Comment: The `beamer` manual explicitly warns "The command `\framebreak` is a shorthand for `\pagebreak<presentation>` and `\noframebreak` is a shorthand for `\nopagebreak<presentation>`.The use of this option isevil. In a (good) presentation you prepare each slide carefully and think twice before putting something on a certain slide rather than on some different slide" so it might be better to use different frames instead of `\framebreak`.